# A Rank Identity with two $n\times n$ matrices

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $A,B$ be two $n\times n$ matrices, and $AB=BA=0$, $r(A)=r(A^2)$. Show that $r(A+B)=r(A)+r(B)$.

Here $r(A)$ is the rank of the matrix $A$.

I have no idea on it after several days' thinking...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first two conditions are saying that $R(B)\subset N(A)$, $R(A)\subset N(B)$ ($N$ = kernel, $R$ = range). The condition that $r(A)=r(A^2)$ means that $N(A^2)=N(A)$ or, equivalently, $R(A)\cap N(A) =\{ 0\}$. Thus we have a direct sum decomposition $\mathbb R^n = N(A)\dotplus R(A)$, and $A:R(A)\to R(A)$ is bijective (because we've divided out the kernel).

Let's now look at $R(A+B)$. First of all,
$$
(A+B)N(A)=BN(A)=B(N(A)\dotplus R(A))=R(B)
$$
because, as we observed, $R(A)\subset N(B)$. Similarly, $(A+B)R(A)=AR(A)=R(A)$. Since $R(B)\subset N(A)$, which is a direct summand of $R(A)$, we have that
$$
r(A+B)=\dim (R(A)+R(B))=\dim R(A)+\dim R(B) = r(A)+ r(B) ,
$$
as claimed.

Comment: The last equality should have some problems. Since $r(A+B)=\rm dim(A+B)\mathbb{F}^n=\rm dim(A+B)(N(A)\oplus R(A))$, and this equals to $\rm dim(A+B)N(A)+\rm dim (A+B)R(A))$?

Comment: Yes, because I showed earlier that these two subspaces ($(A+B)N(A)$ and $(A+B)R(A)$) have zero intersection, so the dimension of the sum is the sum of the dimensions (this is of course not true in general).